# Python Twitter Tools - Adding multiple users to a list fails (lists.members.create_all)

Tags: python, api, list, twitter, http-status-code-404

I am using [Python Twitter Tools API](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter)  to try to add multiple members to a list using [lists.members.create_all](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/lists/members/create_all) of Twitter API v1.1 but I am getting this error:

Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1.1/lists/members/create_all.json 
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}

Other calls work fine and adding single members to a list works fine.  My code is below, would appreciate someone’s help on how to use lists.members.create_all correctly!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twitter import *

OAUTH_TOKEN = 'my oauth token'
OAUTH_SECRET = 'my oauth secret'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'my consumer key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'my consumer secret'

USERNAME =  "my username"
LIST_NAME = "fud"

def main():

  twitter = Twitter(api_version='1.1', auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY,     CONSUMER_SECRET))
  try:

    # view a users lists
    lists = twitter.lists.list(user=USERNAME)
    # create a list
    create_list = twitter.lists.create(name=LIST_NAME)
    # view list members
    list_members = twitter.lists.members(slug=LIST_NAME, owner_screen_name=USERNAME)
    # add single user to list
    twitter.lists.members.create(owner_screen_name=USERNAME, slug=LIST_NAME, screen_name="microsoft")

    # add multiple users to list - fails !!!
    twitter.lists.members.create_all(owner_screen_name=USERNAME, slug=LIST_NAME, screen_name="twitter,python")

  #Produces error:
  #Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1.1/lists/members/create_all.json using parameters: 
  #{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}

  except TwitterHTTPError as twerr:
    import zlib
    print twerr, zlib.decompress(twerr.response_data, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS) # gunzip response error info 

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your call to `create_all()` is correct. The trick is that (the version I recently downloaded of) Python Twitter Tools defaults to a GET request rather than a POST request when it calls the Twitter API to create list members.

The list of methods that require a POST is stored in `twitter_globals.py`. I added `'create_all'`to the `POST_ACTIONS` list and that seemed to work.